# nuget not working for VS 2017

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I try to install any nuget package either through "Manage nuget package for solution" or through command line interface, it won't give any result. "Searching" is keep loading. Any specific reason?

[image]

Comment: i got the error, [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

Comment: not able to browse api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: Is `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` accessible via browser?

Comment: no, this is reason, looks like. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Ask your company's sysadmin. This GET request should work.